# PowerBI publish to Service 500 error "We don't support the option 'HierarchicalNavigation'" (any more?)

Tags: powerbi

I have a report which was working fine in PowerBI Service.

As of this morning it is failing. When I try republish I get a 500 error, looking at the error using [Telerik Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) it says "We don't support the option 'HierarchicalNavigation'". I have no preview features turned on, and the refresh / dataset works in Desktop. I have submitted on the PowerBI forum but adding it here to see if anyone has run in to it before.

Screen shots and http trace of the publish below.

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Length: 443
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-PowerBI-Error-Info: ModelRefresh_ShortMessage_ProcessingError
X-PowerBI-Error-Details: {"error":{"code":"ModelRefresh_ShortMessage_ProcessingError","pbi.error":{"code":"ModelRefresh_ShortMessage_ProcessingError","parameters":[],"details":[{"code":"ModelRefresh_ProcessingErrorLabel","detail":{"type":1,"value":"COM error: Microsoft.Data.Mashup, We cannot generate a query for the given data source reference. Failure reason: We don't support the option 'HierarchicalNavigation'.\u000d\u000aParameter name: HierarchicalNavigation.. "}}]}}}
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: RequestId,X-PowerBI-Error-Info,X-PowerBI-Error-Details
RequestId: 825a548f-1b27-492c-a5f7-accd650fe41f
Date: Wed, 24 Jun 2020 09:07:57 GMT

{"error":{"code":"ModelRefresh_ShortMessage_ProcessingError","pbi.error":{"code":"ModelRefresh_ShortMessage_ProcessingError","parameters":{},"details":[{"code":"ModelRefresh_ProcessingErrorLabel","detail":{"type":1,"value":"COM error: Microsoft.Data.Mashup, We cannot generate a query for the given data source reference. Failure reason: We don't support the option 'HierarchicalNavigation'.\r\nParameter name: HierarchicalNavigation.. "}}]}}}
```

[image]

[image]